# Help identifying shower valve and cartridge

Tags: shower, valve

I can not find a manufacturer name anywhere.  Here's a picture of the valve and the exploded ceramic cartridge and other pieces.   Thank you very much in advance.
[image: valve]
[image: misc parts]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an American Standard, hard to tell as your bottom photo is not that great.

https://www.supply.com/shop?nid=567051&d=1124-16385&wmh_cid=236648182&wmh_aid=14658639502&wmh_kid=69378820539&gclid=Cj0KCQjw_o7NBRDgARIsAKvAgt3kDpHmf2lHcIlhVOvT-_RT2EC3H95CkP3ieOXSRCL3rAhEJijbyEQaAhZmEALw_wcB

Comment: Please take a closeup photo of the escutcheon plate face side up and all the parts. That helps in identification. I add this for future posters.